# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method. mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method.

```
System.Web.Security.MembershipUser mu = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser();

string ID = mu.ProviderUserKey.ToString();

if(db.resume.Where(x => x.employeeID ==Convert.ToInt32(ID)).Count() == 0)
```

Comment: put Convert.ToInt32(ID) in one variable and use that variable in place of it and try again

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the exception message, the `Convert.ToInt32` is not supported inside an expression. Just move it out of the expression:

```
System.Web.Security.MembershipUser mu = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser();

string ID  = mu.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
int    IID = Convert.ToInt32(ID);

if( db.resume.Where(x => x.employeeID == IID).Count() == 0 )
```